# How can I set an object to a constant and display the value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the app component :

```
function App() {
    const [ url, setUrl ] = useState({});
    const fetch = () => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setUrl(res.config.url);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={() => fetch()}>Click</button>
            {url.length ? url : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This actually works and it displays the url string which is `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` when I click the button
on the page but What I really want to do is to set the res whole object to the url constant and then display the config.url like this :

```
const fetch = () => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => {
            setUrl(res);
        });
    };
```

and then :

```
<button onClick={() => fetch()}>Click</button>
            {url.length ? url.config.url : null}
```

but it doesn't work and it also does not throw an error .

How can I set the whole res object to url constant and then display url.config.url when I click the button ?

Comment: you should use useEffect for fetching data

Comment: I know how to do that but I want the fetch happen when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url.config is undefined until the axios request is made. You need to check that url.config is not undefined, if true, display url.config.url, else null.

```
<button onClick={() => fetch()}>Click</button>
        {typeof url.config !== 'undefined' ? url.config.url : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check length from url.config.url, in url length now is miossing

```
{url.config.url.length ? url.config.url : null}
```

Comment: The moment I changed the code to this it throw an error